# Reload color container to null erase TextField inside Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, focus, setstate

I have a `Container` wrapping a `CupertinoTextField` within `Stack`.

When I finish to write on textfield I press a button and clear the focus with `FocusNode`, then reload UI.

I want to reload the color container to null for a use case but when I'm reloading, the textfield seems 'erased'.  Then When I'm clicking again on textfield something is blocking the textfield . Only on the second click I'm able to retrieve textfield focus.

**Here is the preview of what I describe above :**

[image]

**Here is the full code for this :**

```
class EditorTextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditorTextPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditorTextPageState createState() => _EditorTextPageState();
}

class _EditorTextPageState extends State<EditorTextPage> {
  FocusNode focus = FocusNode();
  bool displayEditor = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    focus.addListener(() {
      if (focus.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          displayEditor = true;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: displayEditor ? Colors.red : null,
      child: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 100,
              left: 200,
              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                child: CupertinoTextField(
                  focusNode: focus,
                  minLines: 1,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                  child: CupertinoButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (focus.hasFocus) {
                          focus.unfocus();
                          displayEditor = false;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "DONE",
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why is this happening ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: @pskink thanks for reply.  according answers & comments I realized that i asked this question in a wrong way and it's not what I expected. I know how to apply filters on image in multiple way.  I have to re ask in different way

Comment: @pskink Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for . I can re write a question and accept your code if you want to . 
I can see that your are animating child with offset to mimic the behavior I though it would be a code overload but I was wrong . thanks again very useful

Comment: it's done thank you.
I'm trying to do the same thing on video , but I have to use FFmpeg to apply filters and then I suppose it can't be done with this way too ? Otherwise only moving overlay color above and retrieve it later when selected to apply

Comment: i have no idea how `FFmpeg` is implemented on flutter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is the issue

`Container` uses a `ColoredBox` to display the color. However `ColoredBox` *must* have a color, so in reality `Container` uses `ColoredBox` *only* if `color!=null`.

Which gives you the following widget tree:

- With `color!=null`: `[Container -> ColoredBox -> Stack]`
- With `color==null`: `[Container -> Stack]`

Now if you know how flutter state works, you will know that a state re-attached to the same widget if the widget tree at the same level does not change. Here, since the widget tree above `CupertinoTextField` changes (`ColoredBox` is replaced with a `Stack` or vise versa), the state in not properly rebuild when the color becomes null or stops being null.

Here is what happens in details

1. The first time you focus your `TextField` your color is not null, the widget tree does not change and everything works.
2. When you unfocus, the widget tree is modified so your `TextField` state is lost => The text is "reset"
3. When you refocus, the widget tree changes again, so your `TextField` changes once more, causing the keyboard to be close
4. You are back at 1

For more on Flutter keys see: [When to Use Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)

#### How to solve it

The key (:o) is to make flutter understand that the `Stack` which is bellow the `Container` and then bellow the `ColoredBox` are the same. To do so, assign it a `GlobalKey` (see the video I gave you if you don't understand why).

Here is the implementation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: EditorTextPage()));
}

class EditorTextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditorTextPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditorTextPageState createState() => _EditorTextPageState();
}

class _EditorTextPageState extends State<EditorTextPage> {
  final focus = FocusNode();
  bool displayEditor = true;

  final _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    focus.addListener(() {
      if (focus.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          focus.requestFocus();
          displayEditor = true;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: displayEditor ? Colors.red : null,
        child: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: Stack(
            key: _key,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 100,
                left: 200,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: CupertinoTextField(
                    focusNode: focus,
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLines: 3,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                  child: CupertinoButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (focus.hasFocus) {
                        setState(() {
                          focus.unfocus();
                          displayEditor = false;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "DONE",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for this challenge this was truly fun!

#### Want another fix without keys?

The other option is to avoid modifying the widget tree altogether. The solution is therefore for the color never to be null, set it to transparent for example:

```dart
// GOOD
color: displayEditor ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent

// BAD
color: displayEditor ? Colors.red : null
```

#### What to use ?

I don't know.

In the first option it challenges flutter tree algorithm

In the second option, it's whether rendering a transparent color is challenging for flutter, which I don't know and can't find.

In someone has an opinion this would be very interesting !

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations